# CPAN fails to install Algorithm::CurveFit

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm attempting to install `Algorithm::CurveFit` by simply typing `cpan Algorithm::CurveFit` at the terminal on my Ubuntu VM.

However, this returns the following errors:

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/home/con/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 22 Nov 2021 14:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Algorithm::CurveFit'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.102)
Checksum for /home/con/.local/share/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SM/SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.30)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20210520)
CPAN: Module::Build loaded ok (v0.4231)
Configuring S/SM/SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz with Build.PL
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Algorithm-CurveFit' version '1.05'
  SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
  /home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.0/bin/perl Build.PL -- OK
Running Build for S/SM/SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
Building Algorithm-CurveFit
  SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
  ./Build -- OK
CPAN: CPAN::DistnameInfo loaded ok (v0.12)
Running Build test for SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
t/00pod.t ........ ok   
t/00podcover.t ... ok   
t/01basic.t ...... ok   
t/02bad_deriv.t .. 1/13 
#   Failed test at t/02bad_deriv.t line 50.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 13.
t/02bad_deriv.t .. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/13 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02bad_deriv.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 13 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  3
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=4, Tests=22,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.01 sys +  0.50 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.56 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/4 test programs. 1/22 subtests failed.
  SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
  ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SMUELLER/Algorithm-CurveFit-1.05.tar.gz
```

how can I check `reports` as suggested a the bottom of the summary report?

More importantly, how can I resolve these errors and install `Algorithm::CurveFit`?

Comment: Follow the links from [Algorithm::CurveFit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::CurveFit). Failures similar to yours are reported under "Issues" and there are many red bars under "Testers".

Comment: @choroba indeed, https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=121352 seems to show that version 1.05 is broken for Ubuntu/Debian.  I've tried both on and off perlbrew, and Algorithm::CurveFit is certainly broken. The package hasn't been updated in 11 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source file `CurveFit.pm`, which was downloaded from the package, is symbolically linked somewhere into `@INC`, then the package `Algorithm:::CurveFit` will work properly (apparently).

*However*, `CurveFit.pm` should be modified so that `CurveFit` is called, rather than `Algorithm::CurveFit`

Comment: eh, sounds like you're suggesting "force installing" the module (normally done using `cpan -f Some::Module`) . Forcing the installation of a module that doesn't work is not a good idea...